# config typeorm in a turborepo to create tables

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

i'm trying to setup a project with turborepo and postgresql.

Ok what have i done so far: creating a simple nestjs + typeorm runs very well and Tables are created in postgres-db. So every thing works fine.

The most important part in this is the postgres connection options:

```
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'dbuser',
    password: 'dbuserpw',
    database: 'db_test',
    entities: ['dist/src/**/*.entity.js'],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: 'all',
```

Now I want to use turborepo with workspaces but typorm now seems not to work properly because its installed in projectfolder which is no longer the nestjs project folder. The nestjs project folder is a sub folder of the hole project.

I've tried a lot different ways to give the right path for the entities but they are not created any more in the postgres. Is there any configuration i need to enable the typeorm to get access to the entities in the sub project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Posting all content of the files would decrease the overview of the question.

Meanwhile I found a working solution. In most of the tutorials the usage for database is done in the app.module.ts in the following way:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import config from './typeorm.config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrm.forRoot(config),  // <-- this is not forcing the table initialisation when used with turborepo
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

The solution is to create a connection and synchronize the database in a seperated module like this (Database.ts):

```
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from 
  'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions';
import config from './typeorm.config';
import { Connection, createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class Database {
  public Connection: Connection;
  public Configuration: PostgresConnectionOptions;
  public Environment: string;

  constructor() {
    this.Environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
    this.Configuration = config;

    console.log('Detecting ' + this.Environment + ' environment.');
    console.log(
      'DB information host: ' +
        this.Configuration.host +
        '; user: ' +
        this.Configuration.username,
    );

    this.createConnection();
  }

  private createConnection() {
    createConnection(this.Configuration)
     .then((connection) => {
       console.log('connected!');
        this.Connection = connection;
        connection.synchronize();  // <-- here we create the tables
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
      });
  }
}
```

To make the database accessable in project define it in the bootstrap function in main.ts:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './Api/App/app.module';
import { Database } from './Database';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.get(Database);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```